# c# delete multiple data from database at once

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to create loop that will delete data from my database at the same times.

here's my code.

```
using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows)
    {
        int inventid = Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[bunifuCustomDataGrid1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value);

        mysqlCon.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM bookdb.book WHERE (BookID = @uid)", mysqlCon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uid", inventid);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        mysqlCon.Close();
        GridFill();
    }
}

MessageBox.Show("DOne");
```

I can delete multiple record, but its out if order and chaos.
I hope someone can help me.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I've tried some answers below. this is the code that almost work for me.

```
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            mysqlCon.Open();
            var tr = mysqlCon.BeginTransaction();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows)
            {

                var cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM bookdb.book WHERE (BookID = @uid)");
                cmd.Connection = mysqlCon;
                cmd.Transaction = tr;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", dr.Cells["BookID"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            tr.Commit();
            mysqlCon.Close();

            //////////////////////////
        }

        MessageBox.Show("DOne");
        GridFill();

        ////
        ///
```

the problem is it deleted all rows.

Comment: A more typical approach is to use data binding. If your data was under the control of a [MySqlDataAdapter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm) you would just call it's `Update()` method. If you are manipulating UI elements its a red flag.

Comment: Why are you opening and closing your connection each time you iterate over `bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows`?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the "dr" variable in your loop?  If your `GridFill();` does what I think it does, it probably shouldn't be inside that loop.

Answer (score 2):

use a transaction to send many `ExecuteNonQuery` in one batch

```
mysqlCon.Open();
var tr = mysqlCon.BeginTransaction();

foreach (...)
{
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = mysqlCon ;
    cmd.Transaction = tr;

     ...
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

tr.Commit();
mysqlCon.Close();
```

Comment: i think i use your code in the wrong way.. it deleted all the row at once..

Comment: inside your foreach loop put `Debug.WriteLine($"deleting bookId {dr.Cells["BookID"].Value}")` 
and comment `//cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` to first check if it will delete all the correct bookIDs

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current code, seems like an easy way to do that is to iterate the cells and grab all of the ids from the gridview at once, then send them to the DB to be deleted.

```
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            IEnumerable<int> ids = bunifuCustomDataGrid1
                .Rows[bunifuCustomDataGrid1.CurrentRow.Index]
                .Cells
                .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Value));

            string sql = $"DELETE FROM bookdb.book WHERE BookID IN ({string.Join(", ", ids)})";

            mysqlCon.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlCon);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            mysqlCon.Close();
            GridFill();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("DOne");
```

Comment: just be careful with sql injection here if you don't use `Parameters`, shouldn't be a problem with int tho

Comment: I've tried this code. but i got red line error in .Select... i wonder why.

Comment: you might need some additional code to validate each cell's value to make sure it can be converted to a integer

Answer (score 1):

You could structure your query differently to delete all at once:

```
DELETE FROM bookdb.book WHERE BookID IN (bookid1, bookid2, bookid3, ...)
```

Although this can sometimes lead to a massive SQL query being passed.

As per previous answers, the best solution is to use data binding and call the update method once all items are marked for deletion; this is the equivalent of deleting everything in a transaction.